# Cordova InAppBrowser: close inappbrowser instance from script injected

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I am trying to close the inappbrowser instance from the script injected to it.

Here is code I tried.

```
    ref = window.open(tile.typeContentUrl_en, '_blank', 'location=no');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(data, err) {
      ref.executeScript( {
        code: 'document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("clicked");ref.close() });'
      }, function(){
        console.log('script injected');
      });
    });
```

I got `ref` to be undefined in inappbrowser instance.

Answer (score 2):

`ref` is defined on the cordova webview, but the `inAppBrowser` has it's own webview and `ref` isn't defined there, so you can't close `inAppBrowser` like that.

I haven't tested this, it's a bit hackish, but might work:

```
    ref = window.open(tile.typeContentUrl_en, '_blank', 'location=no');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(data, err) {
      ref.executeScript( {
        code: 'document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("clicked");window.location.href = "close"; });'
      }, function(){
        console.log('script injected');
      });
    });

    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
        if(event.url.indexOf("close") > -1) {
            ref.close();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I checked this But I dont know how the loadstart callback is not getting called. Any idea?

Comment: I've just tested it and it works, but I had to change the if on the loadstart, because the window.location.href = "close"; redirects to the currect page /close, not to an empty page with just close as the url, so check that the page contains close on the url